# Prevent Exception on not found file in ImageResizer?

Tags: c#, exception, imageresizer

I've written a custom `VirtualPathProvider` for ImageResizer.
at `public Stream GetStream(long id)` method I returned `Stream.Null` if file not found.

```
if (!File.Exists(absoluteFilePath)) return Stream.Null;
```

But `ImageResizer` throws an Exception as the following that sent to clients:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Source stream is empty; it has a length of 0. No bytes, no data. We can't work with this.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Source stream is empty; it has a length of 0. No bytes, no data. We can't work with this.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>ImageResizer.ImageProcessingException: Source stream is empty; it has a length of 0. No bytes, no data. We can't work with this.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[ImageProcessingException (0x80004005): Source stream is empty; it has a length of 0. No bytes, no data. We can&#39;t work with this.]
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.GetStreamFromSource(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean&amp; disposeStream, String&amp; path, Boolean&amp; restoreStreamPosition) +806
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.LoadImage(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean restoreStreamPos) +392
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job) +183
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job) +242
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource, Boolean addFileExtension) +107
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource) +23
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings) +18
   ImageResizer.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3.&lt;HandleRequest&gt;b__2(Stream stream) +151
   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClasse.&lt;TryWriteFile&gt;b__d() +322
   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.LockProvider.TryExecute(String key, Int32 timeoutMs, LockCallback success) +333
   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.TryWriteFile(CacheResult result, String physicalPath, String relativePath, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, DateTime sourceModifiedUtc, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean recheckFS) +402
   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.GetCachedFile(String keyBasis, String extension, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, DateTime sourceModifiedUtc, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean asynchronous) +733
   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e) +170
   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context, IResponseArgs e) +35
   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString, IVirtualFile vf) +1491
   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +870
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +69
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34209

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[ImageProcessingException]: Source stream is empty; it has a length of 0. No bytes, no data. We can&#39;t work with this.
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.GetStreamFromSource(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean& disposeStream, String& path, Boolean& restoreStreamPosition)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.LoadImage(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean restoreStreamPos)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource, Boolean addFileExtension)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.<>c__DisplayClass3.<HandleRequest>b__2(Stream stream)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.<>c__DisplayClasse.<TryWriteFile>b__d()
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.LockProvider.TryExecute(String key, Int32 timeoutMs, LockCallback success)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.TryWriteFile(CacheResult result, String physicalPath, String relativePath, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, DateTime sourceModifiedUtc, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean recheckFS)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.GetCachedFile(String keyBasis, String extension, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, DateTime sourceModifiedUtc, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean asynchronous)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context, IResponseArgs e)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString, IVirtualFile vf)
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

**Edit:**
Actually, I want to send nothing to clients if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IVirtualImageProvider` has `FileExists` method with the following signature:

```
bool FileExists(string virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString)
```

I had to implement it correctly. and if it returns false, `ImageResizer` returns nothing without any exceptions for not found files.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are returning a Null Stream and not null.

The difference is subtle, but `Stream.Null` is not `null`, it is an actual stream with a length of 0 (aka an absolutely empty stream). That's why you are getting that exception. In a nutshell:

```
Stream.Null != null
```

Your virtual provider should return null like this:

```
if (!File.Exists(absoluteFilePath)) return null;
```

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/c4c586b58b2211ad0f48f7d8285e951ff6f262f9/Core/ImageBuilder.cs), at line 253 you'll see that ImageResizer throws a FileNotFoundException when you return `null`. How this exception is handled depends on several other factors, but in most configurations it means the user will receive the appropiate 404 HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks @Carlos, but I could find the correct way in `ImageResizer` plugins, I'll post it.